# How to Reuse Same Function in Parent and Child View in SwiftUI with NSManagedObject

Tags: mvvm, core-data, swiftui

Suppose we have a main view `MainView` and a child view `LoginView` which perform login function for user. I have chosen CoreData to store some persisted data like username and password and `@State` in `MainView` to store non-persisted data like logging-in status.

I also want to support automatic login when the user opens the app. So the login function in `LoginView` is also used in `MainView`. My demo code is pasted below.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var loggingIn: Bool = false
    @State private var token: String? = nil
    // `UserInfo` here is a `NSManagedObject` fetched from CoreData
    @ObservedObject private var info: UserInfo 
    
    init() {
        // fetch info from CoreData
    }
    
    func logIn() {
        await MainActor.run {
            self.loggingIn = true
        }
        let token = await performLoginHttpRequest(cred.username!, cred.password!)
        await MainActor.run {
            self.loggingIn = false
            self.token = token
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if logging {
                    ProgressView()
                } else if token == nil {
                    Text("Logged Out")
                } else {
                    Text("Token: \(token!)")
                }
                NavigationLink("Login") {
                    LoginView(info: info, logging: $loggingIn)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await logIn()
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var info: UserInfo
    @Binding var loggingIn: Bool
    @Binding var token: String?
    
    func logIn() async {
        // basically same as in MainView, but
        // `loggingIn` and `token` here is wrapped
        // with `@Binding`
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // UI to login
    }
}
```

As you can see, the problem here is that I have to write the same logic in `MainView` and `LoginView` since I do not know how to share the logic in such configuration.

I have tried some ugly workaround like wrapping the `UserInfo` in another `ObservableObject` and sharing it between views. But nested `ObservableObject` seems not recommended in SwiftUI. Is there any elegant way to implement this?

Comment: Move the logIn function to a separate type, preferably the one that handles the connection to whatever it is the function logs in to.

Comment: Thumb rule: if you want to reuse something then separate it into standalone entity and inject dependency on new entity into original place. Key words: refactoring, dependency injection.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in an extension on the Core Data managed object?

Comment: @Yrb property wrapper is not allowed to use in extension

Comment: What, exactly, did you try to put into the extension? You really haven't shown your code, so we are kind of guessing here. A function, should not have had a property wrapper in it.

Comment: @Yrb I have added more code into the function. The function need to modify the properties like `loggingIn` to update the view. So I thought the `loggingIn` need to be put into the `info` and wrapped with `@Published`.

Comment: Your entities are defined as classes, not structs. You can't use property wrappers except for @Published in a class. But, anything defined as a var in a class is mutable, so you don't need them. Even in structs, variables in functions do not get property wrappers. They may use a variable defined with a property wrapper, but their own variables are not wrapped.